# How to implement User Storage SPI in Keycloak SAML with Authentication from external User database in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, saml

How do I implement User Authentication in SpringBoot using Keycloak SAML with external DB (PostgreSQL)?

My SpringBoot App now uses Keycloak to provide Authentication in SSO for Users stored in Keycloak DB. 
I have User Database with user ids and passwords in one table and user details in other table. 
I want to integrate this two User DBs with Keycloak (something like User Storage SPI) to validate User and provide access token.

I read the documentation for it. But didn't get exactly how to implement the Java EE jar? Which classes to create/implement and which methods?

Comment: as you already mentioned, why don't you want to use Keycloaks `User Federation`? You could integrate your postgres DB to keycloak so it would be possible to login over keycloak with users saved in PG

Comment: Yes that is one option.

Comment: It would involve configuring Keycloak. I'm exploring it. Can I configure this in Spring IDP implementation, since I also already have API that provides user password validation and user details?